# How to get a value from a json string in php?

Tags: php, json

I have tried the this code: **$record = $record['data']->Company;** but it is always returned as null. I have also tried **$record = $record[1]->data->Company;** which also results in a null value. I have read so many answers and tried the solutions but nothing works for me.

Some more experience than me please have a look and let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

```
{
    "1": {
        "index": 1,
        "data": {
            "CONTACTID": "3345923000000546002",
            "SMOWNERID": "3345923000000158021",
            "Contact Owner": "Frank Rosa",
            "First Name": "Administrator",
            "Last Name": "Ian",
            "Email": "poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com",
            "Created Time": "2018-09-19 14:32:35",
            "Modified Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Full Name": "Administrator Ian",
            "Description": "Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard.",
            "Last Activity Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Instagram Url": "http://www.instagram.com/3e_llc",
            "Company": "3ELLC",
            "Website": "https://www.3ellc.org",
            "Phone_1": "(727) 420-1050",
            "Full Address": "2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA",
            "Facebook Url": "http://www.facebook.com/3eLLC/",
            "Logo Url": "https://dev.energypages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/header-logo-57.png",
            "Twitter Url": "http://www.twitter.com/3e_llc",
            "Membership Level": "Basic",
            "Select Service": "Technology",
            "User ID": "347"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the json from my function below:

```
function webhook_listener($request_data){
    $client = new ZohoCRMClient('Contacts', 'API KEY HERE');

    $parameters = $request_data->get_params();

    if( !isset( $parameters['contactId'] ) || empty($parameters['contactId']) ){
        file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'invalid.txt', 'No parameter found');
        return array( 'error' => 'no_parameter_given' );
    }else{
        $companyid = $parameters['contactId'];

        file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'crm.txt', $parameters);

        $record = $client->getRecordById()->id($companyid)->request();

        wp_mail( 'test@gmail.com', 'Post Data', $record );

        $payload = json_decode($record, true);

        $payload = $payload[1]['data']['Company'];

        file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'record.txt', $payload);

       return $payload;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's really tough to get object properties where the property name is a number. It might be best to decode it into an array instead of an object. `$record = json_decode($str, true);`

Comment: @aynber when i use json_decode i also receive a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
<?php
$var = json_decode('{
    "1": {
        "index": 1,
        "data": {
            "CONTACTID": "3345923000000546002",
            "SMOWNERID": "3345923000000158021",
            "Contact Owner": "Frank Rosa",
            "First Name": "Administrator",
            "Last Name": "Ian",
            "Email": "poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com",
            "Created Time": "2018-09-19 14:32:35",
            "Modified Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Full Name": "Administrator Ian",
            "Description": "Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard.",
            "Last Activity Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Instagram Url": "http://www.instagram.com/3e_llc",
            "Company": "3ELLC",
            "Website": "https://www.3ellc.org",
            "Phone_1": "(727) 420-1050",
            "Full Address": "2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA",
            "Facebook Url": "http://www.facebook.com/3eLLC/",
            "Logo Url": "https://dev.energypages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/header-logo-57.png",
            "Twitter Url": "http://www.twitter.com/3e_llc",
            "Membership Level": "Basic",
            "Select Service": "Technology",
            "User ID": "347"
        }
    }
}');

foreach($var as $item) {
    echo $item->data->Company . '<br>';
}
?>
```

The problem was in the key "1", you can't access it like that `$var->1`, but you can iterate it in an array.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do something like this:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "1": {
        "index": 1,
        "data": {
            "CONTACTID": "3345923000000546002",
            "SMOWNERID": "3345923000000158021",
            "Contact Owner": "Frank Rosa",
            "First Name": "Administrator",
            "Last Name": "Ian",
            "Email": "poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com",
            "Created Time": "2018-09-19 14:32:35",
            "Modified Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Full Name": "Administrator Ian",
            "Description": "Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard.",
            "Last Activity Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Instagram Url": "http://www.instagram.com/3e_llc",
            "Company": "3ELLC",
            "Website": "https://www.3ellc.org",
            "Phone_1": "(727) 420-1050",
            "Full Address": "2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA",
            "Facebook Url": "http://www.facebook.com/3eLLC/",
            "Logo Url": "https://dev.energypages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/header-logo-57.png",
            "Twitter Url": "http://www.twitter.com/3e_llc",
            "Membership Level": "Basic",
            "Select Service": "Technology",
            "User ID": "347"
        }
    }
}';
$payload = json_decode($json, true);
$error = json_last_error();
if ($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new RuntimeException("JSON decode error: $error");
}
var_dump($payload[1]['data']['Company']);
```

As result you will see:

```
string(5) "3ELLC"
```

In case you don't need associative array but class, try this:

```
$payload = json_decode($json);
$error = json_last_error();
if ($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new RuntimeException("JSON decode error: $error");
}
var_dump($payload->{"1"}->data->Company);
```

Result will be the same.

Comment: So i ran your answer in postman and the value returned was null

Comment: I should also mention i am using the code in a function

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to decode the record like this.

   $array = json_decode($record, true);
2. Then you can access the data like this.

   echo $array['1']['data']['Company'];

Checkout it out here, https://www.tehplayground.com/UpHMPFxfSKdxXBmn

Have a good day!

Comment: Try this out , if it doesn't work I'll try to help you.

Comment: Please format your question as per the SO standards.

Comment: You should print the $record before you try to decode it and check if there is any data there.

Comment: @urreeK in my function i return $record and i receive the json in my post, but trying to get the value from the json it is always null.

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump($record) ?

Comment: @urreeK var_dump($record) give me: Unexpected 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Having the json resource in the data.json file

```
$json = file_get_contents('/tmp/data.json');
```

Or in a string

```
$json = '{
    "1": {
        "index": 1,
        "data": {
            "CONTACTID": "3345923000000546002",
            "SMOWNERID": "3345923000000158021",
            "Contact Owner": "Frank Rosa",
            "First Name": "Administrator",
            "Last Name": "Ian",
            "Email": "poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com",
            "Created Time": "2018-09-19 14:32:35",
            "Modified Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Full Name": "Administrator Ian",
            "Description": "Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard.",
            "Last Activity Time": "2018-09-20 02:48:51",
            "Instagram Url": "http://www.instagram.com/3e_llc",
            "Company": "3ELLC",
            "Website": "https://www.3ellc.org",
            "Phone_1": "(727) 420-1050",
            "Full Address": "2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA",
            "Facebook Url": "http://www.facebook.com/3eLLC/",
            "Logo Url": "https://dev.energypages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/header-logo-57.png",
            "Twitter Url": "http://www.twitter.com/3e_llc",
            "Membership Level": "Basic",
            "Select Service": "Technology",
            "User ID": "347"
        }
    }
}';
```

Try the following

```
$record = (array) json_decode($json);

print_r($record[1]->data->Company);
```

Output

```
3ELLC
```